# Trying to remove multiple space in txt file using python

Tags: python

I am trying to remove multiple spaces from a text file containing thousands of strings. Please see attached example of the file I am using.

[image: current state of files]

I need only single space between files, it should look something like this

[image: The end result I am hoping for]

This is the code I am trying but its not working

```
with open('nog_space.txt') as f:

new_list = []

for line in f:
    split = line.split()
    new_list = " ".join(new_list.split())

print(new_list)

with open('no_space_update.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in new_list:
        f.write(i)
        f.write('\n')
```

I tried reading documentation and other similar issues but I am stuck, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the keyword you're looking for is 'trim' see https://www.journaldev.com/23625/python-trim-string-rstrip-lstrip-strip.

Comment: actually you don't need python. with any text editor just replace "  " (two spaces)  to " " (single space). Click replace all several times until only single spaces remain.

Comment: doing it to thousands of text

Comment: yes, the option "replace all" will replace all the text in the file, no matter how many lines you have

Comment: Are you aware that the `mv` command doesn't care at all how many spaces there are between the file names?